# using dd command in c program

Tags: c, dd

I need to use the following code in my c code and compile.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=400 of=/dev/udp/SrcAddress.ai_addr/8000
```

This is giving the error

```
‘dd’ was not declared in this scope
```

How can I use this command inside my c code?

Comment: `dd` is a shell command, not a c function :o

Comment: Umm... how well do you know C? Try the `system` function.

Comment: `system()` is the way to execute any shell command from C.

Comment: I suspect that `SrcAddress.ai_addr` is not a verbatim string but a place where you want to substitute a variable.  But to tell you how to do that, we need to know what operating system you're using, because `/dev/udp` is nonstandard.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `dd` like that. Your C program is not a terminal and you cannot perform shell commands by just writing them in your code. One way to perform what you want is by using `popen` as following.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 FILE *fd = popen("dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=400 of=/dev/udp/SrcAddress.ai_addr/8000","w");
 pclose(fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that what you actually want to do is write the *equivalent* of this `dd` operation in C.  That would look something like this.

```
int send_n_random_bytes_udp(unsigned int n, const struct sockaddr_in *dest)
{
    int rng = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
    if (rng == -1) return -1;
    int sk  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM);
    if (sk  == -1) { close(rng); return -1; }

    int status = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char byte;
        if (read(rng, &byte, 1) != 1 ||
            sendto(sk, &byte, 1, 0,
                   (const struct sockaddr *)dest,
                   sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 1) {
            status = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    close(sk);
    close(rng);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: For that matter, they could use C to generate the random numbers instead of reading `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @yellowantphil I assume they want cryptographically sound random numbers. Reading `/dev/urandom` is much easier than dumping an implementation of ChaCha20 into the answer box. ;-)

Comment: In that case, they ought to be using `/dev/random`.

Comment: @yellowantphil The current thinking is that `/dev/urandom` is cryptographically sound "enough" and `/dev/random` is unnecessary.  IIRC FreeBSD has made them the same, even.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @yellowantphil See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209/when-to-use-dev-random-vs-dev-urandom and https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/